# AWS DMS to migrate FROM RDS Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws-dms

can I migrate from AWS RDS to standalone Postgres instance using AWS DMS?

I [RTFM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html), but It does not state anywhere clearly If I can or not. In theory migration should be the same - create supporting scheme in RDS and move on. But have anyone done it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, from [AWS DMS manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html):

> AWS Database Migration Service (AWS DMS) can migrate your data to and from most widely used commercial and open-source databases such as Oracle, PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL Server, Amazon Redshift, Amazon Aurora, MariaDB, and MySQL. The service supports homogeneous migrations such as Oracle to Oracle, and also heterogeneous migrations between different database platforms, such as Oracle to MySQL or MySQL to Amazon Aurora. **The source or target database must be on an AWS service**.

In your case the source is on an AWS service, and if by "standalone" you mean a PostgreSQL instance on EC2 machine, then your target is as well. So, based on that, then answer should be "yes".

Comment: thank you for the answer. I've read this block of docs and came to conclusion that it is more yes, then no. It's just I can't try it myself, so I'm asking if anyone actually done that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. We have moved data from RDS Postgres to Postgres Installed on EC2 Instance using DMS and works great so far. Make sure to create endpoints for the source/target and create a replication instance and you are good to go

Comment: Thank you. But I know how to move data with logical replication. I wonder if I can **using AWS DMS**

Comment: Sorry, yes I did mean through AWS DMS. I updated my answer to reflect that. Thanks!